# Highcharts print bug on Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing, highcharts, multipage

I am using Highcharts Version 2.2.5.

Recently we've found an issue with printing on firefox 13.0.1 (it works with IE and chrome)

Test is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/a2avu/6/

When clicking on the print button it will print only the first page and second page will be  blank.

How can i fix it? Is there any mistake in the chart definition?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Firefox 13.0.1. You should try with a new profile. You can do that starting firefox from the command line.

```
firefox -ProfileManager --no-remote
```

and then creating a profile and press "Start Firefox".

If the problem still exists, you should tell us which OS you use. If this solves your problem, then your firefox profile is buggy.

Comment: i tried to start from command line firefox -ProfileManager --no-remote and firefox -p problem still exists.. My OS is WIN7 HOME PRE 64BIT problem screenshot at imageshack.us/photo/my-images/98/highcharts.png

Comment: could you check your link? The picture doesn't load for me.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/98/highcharts.png/   **As you can see the chart print is cut after the first page at firefox.**